# Arrayformula or map formula for index-matching

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

In [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i3S1xVZocZ6PeLVCgunuGkPcwc_AhvdlMxj4GRFxCw0/edit?usp=sharing)

Col A:   If value row value of Amount (col C) is >0, it returns $A$1. If row value of Amount (col C) is <0 it returns the value of the column header (rows D to G)

`=iferror(if(C4>0,$A$1,index($D$3:$3,match(C4,D4:4,0))),"")`

Col B is similar:  If value row value of Amount (C) is >0, it returns the value of the column header (rows D to G). If row value of Amount (C) is <0, it returns $A$1

**I am looking for a formula which will do the equivalent of this index(match**

**However, I am looking for an arrayformula or map style formula equivalent so that if new rows of data are added, the formula will work without having to be copied down into the new rows**

Thanks for your help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Added formula to your [sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i3S1xVZocZ6PeLVCgunuGkPcwc_AhvdlMxj4GRFxCw0/edit#gid=1347025551):

```
=byrow(D4:G,lambda(z,if(counta(z)=0,,if(offset(index(z,,1),,-1)>0,{A1,+filter(D3:G3,z<>"")},{+filter(D3:G3,z<>""),A1}))))
```

[image]